# Convert existing attribute to a CustomAttributeBuilder for insertion into dynamically generated class

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, attributes, custom-attributes

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way take a class such as:

```
public class ModelX {
    [TheAttribute(1, "two")]
    [SomeOtherAttribute(Three.Four)]
    public string Foo {get;set;}
```

And copy these onto

```
public class DynamicallyCreatedModelX {
    [TheAttribute(1, "two")]
    [SomeOtherAttribute(Three.Four)]
    public string Foo {get;set;}
```

I'm not what would be the optimal way to pass the data over from the known to the dynamic class.

Comment: How are you creating your dynamic class?

Comment: assembly.DefineDynamicModule(...).DefineType(...), so I have builders that want CustomAttributeBuilder. I was able to use the SetCustomAttribute for static attributes I want to place on my type, but I'm not sure what would be optimal for copying currently unknown attributes.

Answer (score 0):

set attributes for properties (or any members) can be like this:

```
PropertyBuilder property = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(...);
property.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(TheAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) }), new object[] { 1, "two" }));
property.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(SomeOtherAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(Three.Four) }), new object[] { Three.Four }));
```